# Is there any Azure service that can simulate the concept of a global Azure 'variable' to hold a single value?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am looking for some Azure service that can store a value and then I can fetch it from any other Azure service. It's a storage basically but extremely lightweight storage -- it should allow one to define a variable for a given subscription and then its value can be updated from any other Azure service. In Azure Data Factory there is a recent introduction of global parameter at data factory level , even this could serve purpose to some limited extent if it was mutable, but it's a parameter not a variable. So its value can't be updated. Even if I can get some solution that will work within data factory that's fine too. One could always store such a value in SQL or blob but that sounds like an overkill. Having a global Azure variable is a genuine requirement -- so wondering if there is anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider [Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts). You can define there a secret to hold this value. However I'm not sure what integration with other Azure services you need.

Comment: yea thanks, I thought of this earlier though I thought there is something simpler and more lightweight. But your answer helps in knowing that there isn't anything else.

Answer (score 1):

you have several options:

1. cosmosdb table api
2. redis
3. table storage

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/data-store-overview#keyvalue-stores